# CRM Custom Report

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I made a CRM custom report with a custom code and i`m getting an error on the CRM when uploading saying that “The report server has RDLSandboxing enabled and the report contains custom code. Remove the Code element from the report definition.”

Now my question is , Is it possible to disable the RDLSandboxing?

If yes, where do I start?

Here is the code used in the report

```
Public Function Divider(ByVal Dividend As Decimal, ByVal Divisor As Decimal) 
  If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0 Then 
    Return 0 
  Else 
    Return Dividend / Divisor 
  End If 
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have CRM Online or On-Premise?
Also what custom code are you using could you give an example?

Comment: I have use CRM Online.                                                                           Below is the code :

Public Function Divider(ByVal Dividend As Decimal, ByVal Divisor As Decimal)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0 Then
Return 0
Else
Return Dividend / Divisor
End If
End Function

Comment: That code doesn't look too bad. Maybe you've included some libraries you don't need?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change anything to the RDL Sandboxing when using CRM Online.
Here are a few links that contain more information on the subject.

- [RDL Sandboxing for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547428.aspx)
- [Custom code that is allowed for use in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online FetchXML Reports](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/2600639/custom-code-that-is-allowed-for-use-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-f)

You will have to change your custom code to any of the accepted Methods & Classes as you have no access to the Report Server

Answer (score 0):

Reports within CRM Online don't allow custom code.
Uploading a report that contains any custom code will generate the error that you're receiving

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that the CRM report server has RDLSandboxing enabled, which is an important security feature that helps to protect the CRM report server from malicious code. Disabling this feature is not recommended. To address the error, you should remove the custom code from your report definition and use built-in expressions or functions instead. For instance, you can use an expression to perform the division operation. You can achieve the same result as your custom code without violating the RDLSandboxing security feature by using built-in expressions or functions. Once you have removed and replaced the custom code with the expression, you should be able to upload and run the report without any issues.

Code:-

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Divisor.Value) OR Fields!Divisor.Value = 0, 0, 
Fields!Dividend.Value / Fields!Divisor.Value)
```